# Can I use Google's Datastore for a desktop application?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I was asked to provide a quick and easy solution for storing data in Java, and since I had experience in working with Google App engine, I thought that I could just use their Google Cloud Datastore (https://developers.google.com/datastore/). But, the project that I'm working on now is a desktop application with a GUI. My question is, would I be able to use these services even though the application I'm developing isn't a web app, and uses Java's GUI components?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can. The [Cloud Datastore](https://developers.google.com/datastore/) gives you access to the normal App Engine Datastore but does not require you to be running a web app. You can then use all the normal Datastore tools that App Wngine provides to manage your data.

You'll want to follow [these instructions](https://developers.google.com/datastore/docs/activate#service_account) for setting up your Cloud Datastore project to connect from your GUI app.

Answer (score 0):

It depends. dev_appserver isn't a hardened environment, and simulating a deployed environment is a priority over performance. dev_appserver provides a *simulated* Datastore, not the real thing. That said, I've built several single-user, locally-served web apps using both the Java and Python dev_appservers, because it was a convenient way to get started and performed well enough for my purposes.

Answer (score -1):

I don't see why not,

Not a java dude, but it says it exposes a HTTP interface, so this:

code.google.com/p/google-http-java-client/‎

should allow you to communicate with it I believe.

Also perhaps have a read of this question

[Database for Google App Engine and desktop application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18401700/database-for-google-app-engine-and-desktop-application)